# How to configure Kotlin Androidx dependencies for unit testing as well as succesfully writing the unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-testing

Up and running with android, and at the same time trying to understand what I am doing.

I have tried all sorts, read as much resources as I can related to unit testing android. One way or another I still come short and error after error when I run the unit tests.

Instrumented testing was straight forward and I actually managed to satisfactory getting it working.

Now onto unit test and I have gotten tired of changing one dependency to another because one is not compatible with the version of android. Finding these dependencies is a bit of sweat, I have relied more on this forum than the docs to figure out how to piece things together.

Here is my dependency configuration:
[image]

Here is my MainActivity class

[image]

And here is my test class set up against the activity. It is fairly simple for practical purposes:

[image]

I get this error now, after resolving a bunch of other errors:

[image]

I am basically spending an awful lot of time on configuration than doing what I need to do - write the unit test.

How can I go about successfully configuring the dependencies to enable me to write a successful unit test. If my tests are also wrong, how can I correctly change them?

Comment: Please read the "how to ask" guide regarding posting images https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As the error says, you're missing cglib.  Mockito 2.4 is pretty ancient.  Is there a reason you're using such an old version?

In general, though, you're going to have a bad time if you're not careful with managing what the Activity is going to access in the Android framework and managing the lifecycle.  What you have right now will not call onCreate and things like findViewById and StartActivity are going to have problems without the backing Android framework.

The android guide to unit testing here is helpful https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests

Comment: That is a very good point regarding the onCreate method. You see I am following a book on this topic but came short on many occasions. I'll take a look at the docs provided and give this one more go. Tbh the amount of time I have invested in this I might as well move on if I fail to get anywhere. Regarding the images, I was having a hard time adding the code, the format was getting thrown off every time I added the code. Especially the last image. It would not format properly. This is every time I tried to submit